# Is there any way to save as PNG using image processor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I use following settings to save my open documents as JPG.
[image]

Whenever I designs (4-5) for any campaign, I just specify my output folder and run it. It helps me a lot.

But I use this only for feedback on designs. Once approved, I need the final outputs in PNG.

Is there any way to save them as PNG using image processor in my specified directory?

Comment: Relevant question from another SE site: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/31128/9161